# Locating SQL behind PowerPivot Data Model

Tags: powerpivot

I have a PowerPivot data model using Excel 2013 that someone has given me. However, I can't find the SQL code used to pull in the tables from the data warehouse for the model. I'm fairly new at this. Is there a way to find the code behind the model? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple to find. You have to opne yout excel and the tab Data and click connection:

[image]

After that you have a new windows with 2 connection:
-This workbook data model ( powerpivot)
- The real connection to sql:

[image]

if you click proprieties you can finde server and database name under the definition tab:

[image]